# Four Tables show single occurrence for outer most table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a set of tables as follows:

```
    SELECT applicants.id, companies.name, employees.first_name, departments.name, applied_date
    FROM applicants
    INNER JOIN departments ON applicants.department_id = departments.id
    INNER JOIN companies ON departments.university_id = companies.id
    INNER JOIN employees ON applicants.student_id = employees.id
```

Which produces something like:

```
    1   Apple   Chuck   hr              2013-09-24 
    2   Apple   Chuck   finance         2013-09-25 
    3   Apple   Chuck   outside sales   2013-09-25 
    4   Google  Chuck   outside sales   2015-10-25 
    7   Google  Dottie  product         2015-10-26 
    6   Apple   Dottie  product         2015-10-26 
    5   Apple   Dottie  sales           2015-10-25 
    8   Apple   Blake   product         2015-10-26 
    9   Google  Blake   product         2015-10-26
```

What I am attempting to do, is show the first applied_date to each company for each person.

Resulting in:

```
    1   Apple   Chuck   hr              2013-09-24 
    4   Google  Chuck   outside sales   2015-10-25 
    7   Google  Dottie  product         2015-10-26 
    6   Apple   Dottie  product         2015-10-26 
    8   Apple   Blake   product         2015-10-26 
    9   Google  Blake   product         2015-10-26
```

I have tried going from Companies and traversing down to applicants and vice versa. Additionally I have tried a number of LEFT JOIN's to no avail.

I feel like this must be trivial for some... Any direction would be great.

Comment: It's trivial in PostgreSQL, but not in MySQL, so what's your DBMS?

Comment: I am using PostgresSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a PostgreSQL extension to Standard SQL, `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(companies.name, employees.first_name) 
   applicants.id, companies.name, employees.first_name, departments.name, applied_date
FROM applicants
INNER JOIN departments ON applicants.department_id = departments.id
INNER JOIN companies ON departments.university_id = companies.id
INNER JOIN employees ON applicants.student_id = employees.id
ORDER BY companies.name, employees.first_name, applied_date
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I had a feeling I was missing something. Curious, if the query had been ran in another RDMS, would the solution be involve a left join?

Comment: @joenotjoe: Left joins will not help in this case, the Standard SQL solution applies `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.name, e.first_name), a.id, c.name, e.first_name, d.name, applied_date
FROM applicants a INNER JOIN
     departments d
     ON a.department_id = d.id INNER JOIN
     companies c
     ON d.university_id = c.id INNER JOIN
     employees e
     ON a.student_id = e.id
ORDER BY c.name, e.first_name, applied_date desc;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a special feature of Postgres.  It takes one row for each group as defined by the values of the keys in parentheses (which should also be the first keys in the `ORDER BY`).  It then chooses the first row in the group, based on the remaining keys in the `ORDER BY`, so this chooses the most recent date for the `name`/`first_name` combination.